# All the pages are invisible

Tags: google-docs

I have a google doc where I have about 40 pages. But now everything is blank. The doc scrolls but I dont see any pages.

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using and what's its version info? You might be able to find that at `about:version`. Do you see any error messages in the developer console?